# SQL - Parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle

So In the tables I'm trying to create a foreign key relationship between `SECTION` and `INSTRUCTOR`, where `INSTRUCTOR_ID` in table `SECTION` is a foreign key pointing to the primary key INSTRUCTOR_ID in the table INSTRUCTOR.  Unfortunately,
I'm getting this error:

```
parent keys not found
02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
*Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
           child records.
*Action:   Obvious
Vendor code 2298
```

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because there are already some row of data in section table. And those rows have such values for instructor_id which are not present in instructor table.

To create a constraint in a table which already have some data you must ensure that existing data is valid against that constraint otherwise it's not possible to create that constraint.

So, either you have to delete all data from section table or you to update the instructor_id values in section table so that they matches with any values of instructor_id column of instructor table.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems obvious here, though it might not be. But, on the first look, I think few Instructor_ID values in SECTION table are not present in INSTRUCTOR table which is why you got the error of "parent keys not found". Are you sure that all the Instructor_ID present in SECTION table are also present in INSTRUCTOR table?